# Referencing equations in flalign

Tags: cross-referencing, flalign

Hello I am using flalign as

```
\begin{flalign}
    A=&3x+5xy\\
    B=&6xy+3x^2y
\end{flalign}
```

I want to reference equation number of B, but I don't know how to. Anyone to the help, please.

If it is just an equation, I usually do

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
 f(x)=3x
\end{equation}
This is equation \ref{eq1}
```

but I am not sure how to reference second equation in flalign.

Comment: You can have one label for each line (b.t.w., using `\cref`, from `cleveref`, will save you having to type ‘equation’).

Answer (score 1):

Just as you normally would using `\label` and `eqref`. (I have corrected the `&` placement to be `&=` for correct spacing.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
A&=3x+5xy\\
B&=6xy+3x^2y \label{key}
\end{flalign}
We use \eqref{key} in something. 
\end{document}
```